# Not able to use for loop in Ansible

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-template

```
 - name: checking whether symbolic link created or not
       {% for item in ['/opt/lsf/bin/bsh','/opt/praveen'] %}
       {{ item }}:
         debug:
           msg: "{{ item }}"
       {% endfor %}
```

Please let me know if anything is wrong in this

Comment: This is not a valid ansible task. It does not even restpect yaml syntax. For this specific case, see [loops](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html)

Comment: I resolved your issue you can check the first solution

Answer (score 1):

Resolved Using Ansible:
[image]

You need to create a **Playbook.yaml** :

```yaml
---
- hosts: all
  become: yes #  ask ansible to be a super user (working like sudo )
  roles:
    - template-module
```

also Create a role for templates:
[image]

In you **main.yaml** put this code:

```yaml
- name: checking whether symbolic link created or not
  template:
    src: test.j2
    dest: /tmp/test.yaml
```

and in you jinaj2 **"test.j2"** template put this ;

```py
       {% for item in ['/opt/lsf/bin/bsh','/opt/praveen'] %}
       {{ item }}:
         debug:
           msg: "{{ item }}"
       {% endfor %}
```

This can hel you to resolve your issue.